# How do you execute a command in the background with a Chef recipe on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, java, chef

I have a Java application I am deploying with Chef.  I would like it to start, and allow the Chef client to exit.  However, it seems like chef-client waits for the command to finish, no matter how I run it.

I have tried:

1. Executing `javaw` with the `execute` resource
2. Executing with `start`
3. Executing with `start /B`
4. Creating a batch script and running that with `start` and `start /B`

Is there a way to run the Java program without blocking chef-client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by making the program a service, and running it that way. A Windows service requires either a code change or a service wrapper.  [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) worked for me. YAJSW is easy to set up, since it includes scripts to help generate configuration, install as a service, and run the service. In the chef recipe, I include the configuration file generated on a test machine, and install and run the service with the build in scripts.

One gotcha was making sure the user running the service can run services.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** the answer below works on Linux, not Windows. It's probably not what you need, but since I wrote it already without noticing that it's a Windows question, I'll leave it for the sake of potential future readers.

**This is how it can be done on Linux:**

I guess you could write a bash script and run it as a service.
I'm using the `daemon` package to do this. Here is an example recipe you can start with:

```
# the package that lets you easily define new services
package "daemon"

# script file used by service to launch your java program
file "/my/path/run_script.cmd" do
    content "java --flag1 --flag2 -jar /my/program.jar\n"
end

# setup the service (based on the script above),
# start it, and make it start at boot
cookbook_file '/etc/init.d/myservice' do
    source 'etc_initd_myservice'
end
service "myservice" do
    supports :restart => true, :start => true, :stop => true, :reload => true
    action [:enable]
end
```

Note that you'll need to add a file named `etc_initd_myservice` to your cookbook. You can use the content in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150888/221917) as basis for this file. This is the file that employs the "daemon" package to run a script as a service.

Also, [the following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938314/chef-how-to-run-a-template-that-creates-a-init-d-script-before-the-service-is-c) might contain relevant information if you're having problems with defining a service and creating its init.d script in the same recipe.

Comment: I wish creating a service in WIndows was as easy as it is in Linux. Unfortunately, you need either a program coded to be a service, or use a service wrapper.